# vs code search regex

Tags: regex, replace, visual-studio-code, find

I have a .html file that was created with microsoft word. It contains a bunch of 0xA0 characters which I want to replace with a space using VS code. I have tried the following in the "find" box.

```
\0xA0 (regex off)
\0xA0 (regex on)
\xA0 (regex off)
\xA0 (regex on)
/\xA0/ (regex on)
```

None of these find a match. So what is the correct entry for finding a single "OxA0" or any other hex character in vs code?

Comment: Try `\u00A0`, too. Anyway, you may also try to type it into the search box: turn on NumLock, hold `ALT` and type `0160` on the numeric keypad, and release `ALT`.

Comment: `\u00A0` indeed helps in VS Code

Answer (score 1):

To find and replace a specific character with a hex code, such as `0xA0`, in VS Code, you can use the regular expression feature. Here's the correct entry for finding a single `0xA0` character:

1. Press `Ctrl + F` to open the Find dialog.
2. Click on the icon that looks like a dot with asterisks (`.*`) to enable the regex mode.
3. Enter `\xA0` in the search box.
4. Press `Enter` to find the first occurrence of `0xA0`.
5. To replace it with a space, click on the "Replace" icon (looks like a square with an arrow pointing to the right) or press `Ctrl + H` to open the Replace dialog.
6. Enter a space character (``) in the "Replace with" field.
7. Click on the "Replace" button to replace the `0xA0` character with a space.
8. If you want to replace all occurrences, click on the "Replace All" button.

Make sure that you have the correct file open in VS Code and that you are searching within the file by following the steps above.